# Htaccess rewrite image URLs in SEO friendly way

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have these images uploaded in my site with some random numbers and text as their names and I want them to be loaded in the site with a proper name.

How the image loads now with its absolute URL

> http://www.example.com/uploads/folder_n/t_xxxx_20170407030916_888867.jpeg

How I want the image to load is,

> http://www.example.com/uploads/folder_n/itemname-thumb-xxxx_20170407030916_888867.jpeg

I tried this but it's not working.

```
RewriteRule ^uploads/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)-thumb-([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)$ /uploads/$1/t_$3 [R=301,NC]
```

- "/folder_n/" -> dynamically changes this folder name
- "t_" -> should be "thumb-"
- "itemname" -> dynamically change
- "xxxx_20170407030916_888867.jpeg" -> this also changes dynamically

How can I do this using htaccess rewrite rules?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^(uploads/[\w-]+)/[\w-]+-thumb-([\w.-]+)/?$ /$1/t_$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Okay now this worked but it redirects to the absolute path.

Comment: RewriteBase isn't set.

Comment: In that case what do you mean by `it redirects to the absolute path`? On my Apache it loads `http://localhost/uploads/folder_n/t_xxxx_20170407030916_888867.jpeg`

Comment: when the rewritten URL is loaded in the browser it goes to the absolute URL "http://localhost/uploads/folder_n/t_xxxx_20170407030916_8888‌​67.jpeg". Can we keep the changed URL and still load the real image?

Comment: It's used in a Symfony site

Comment: ok you can remove `R` flag from above rule to make it: `RewriteRule ^(uploads/[\w-]+)/[\w-]+-thumb-([\w.-]+)/?$ /$1/t_$2 [L,NC]` and keep this rule at top. Though keep in mind that internal rewrite rules (without `R` flag) don't work with many php frameworks.